# Build string on one line PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to build a combination of numbers and letters separated by - (minus sign). i.e 1-R-3. The first number are in an array called $Points ,the letters are stored in a array called $Color and the last number is in a third array called $Points2;

```
$Points = [1,2,3,4];
$Color = [R,B,V,Y];
$Points = [1,2,3,4];
```

I want the result to be one one row 1-R-1, 2-B-2 and so on. Now the result outputs as:

1

(minus sign)

R

(minus sign)

3
`

```
$Bind = "-";
$foo = $Points[0] . $Bind . $Points[1];
```

I have tried to convert the integer to a string by (String) but have not worked.

Can somebody help me to get the result on one line? I bet i'm missing something easy!

EDIT: The format in the arrays where incorrect since I forgot ->plaintext when doing my web-scraping.

/U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be occurring because of the tabs or carriage return:

```
<?php


$points = [1,2,3,4];
$colors = ['R','B','V','Y'];

$bind = '-';

$foo = [];

for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    $foo[$x] = $points[$x].$bind.$colors[$x].$bind.$points[$x]; 
}

foreach($foo as $value) {
  echo $value.'<br>';
}

?>
```

Result:

```
1-R-1
2-B-2
3-V-3
4-Y-4
```

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately. I have updated my post.

Comment: Great! The code works. I also found out that I forgot ->plaintext when storing the values in the array (I'm scraping). The help from @Dave with the quotes was also a tip! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$Points = [1,2,3,4];
$Color = ['R','B','V','Y'];

foreach ($Points as $point=>$value) {
    echo $value . '-' . $Color[$point] . '-' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note that the values in the `$Color` array need to be in quotes to avoid errors.

Answer (score 2):

You have two arrays called `$Points`, so I've renamed one.

This just combines the three arrays by using `foreach` and using the key of each element and using it to access the other arrays at the same index...

```
$Points = [1,2,3,4];
$Color = ['R','B','V','Y'];
$Points1 = [1,2,3,4];
$bind = "-";

foreach ( $Points as $key => $val ) {
    echo $val.$bind.$Color[$key].$bind.$Points1[$key].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php `join` function. For example:

```php
$results = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($Points); $i++) {
    $results[] = join('-', [$Points[$i], $Colors[$i], $Points2[$i]]);
}

// Now you have your combined values in $results array
var_export($results);
```

Comment: The integers and letters are not from the same array. I tried $result = join('-', $Points[0]); But got an error.

Comment: Can you please add an example of your `$Points` variable value.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine array into one string like

```
 <?php


 $Points = [1,2,3,4];
 $Color = ['R','B','V','Y'];
 $Points = [1,2,3,4];
 $result='';

 $bind='-';

 foreach ($Points as $index => $value) {
   $result .= $value .$bind . $Color[$index] . $bind . $value.PHP_EOL;
 }

 echo $result;
 ?>
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3c2adc62740d9ed615068f57038ac7beb5eccde)